# Connection refused: connect whilst running Apache Zeppelin.

Tags: apache, apache-zeppelin

I have downloaded Spark 2.1.0 and Apache Zeppelin 0.7.0. I have edited my environment variables for Spark, Java and Winutils (as i am using windows 10). I have edited the zeppelin-env.sh and zeppelin-site.xml to export my JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME. I edited zeppelin-site.xml to change the port number as 8080 was already in use. I have opened command line as an administrator, changed to the zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all directory and run the command bin\zeppelin.cmd. I opened the browser and navigated to localhost:8090. Zeppelin opens and the green light in the top right corner appears suggesting i am connected to the server. Once i run the "load data into table" tutorial i receive an error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:90)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.init(RemoteInterpreter.java:209)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:375)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:105)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:365)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

No logs are available in the logs folder. Everything is printed in the command line. The %md interpreter works as the code from "Welcome to Zeppelin" works fine after i run it.

I have tried altering the memory as per ZEPPELIN_305 and ZEPPELIN-449 on issues.apache.org. I have tried turning off windows firewall. I have uninstalled and reinstalled to ensure it wasn't an error i caused myself but nothing seems to work.

Has anybody had the same/similar problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be in the editing the wrong config file. Since you are on Windows 10 you want to edit the zeppelin-env.cmd (and not the zeppelin-env.sh which is intended for Linux). See the [link](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/install/install.html#starting-apache-zeppelin) to the Zeppelin install guide.